# What's the difference of SELECT and SELECT IN in sql?

Tags: sql

- 1. The difference of the two statements?
- 2. Is the second statemnet faster than the first statement?

First statement :

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 2197176;
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 74877;
```

Second statement:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id IN(2197176, 74877, ...)
```

**UPDATE**:

- 3. If the time complexity of first statement is `m*n`, will the second statement be `m*n`?

> `m`: the time complexity of `SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 2197176;`.
>
> `n`: the amount of ids.

**UPDATE**:

- 4. In the following two cases, which case is faster? And why?

Assuming the table is as follows:

```
| ID        | FLAG   |
| ----------|:------:|
| 2197176   | true   | 
| 74877     | false  |
```

First case:

```
List ids = getIds(); 
for(id in ids){
    result = getResultFromFirstStatement(id);  //one sql statement
    if(result.flag) { do sth ...}
}
```

Second case:

```
List ids = getIds(); 
results = getResultFromSecondStament(ids); //`n` sql statements
for(r in results){
    if(r.flag) { do sth ...}
}
```

Comment: at first statement you query two times that why it take more time

Comment: You need to use `union` if you use first approach otherwise you won't get the result in a single table form.

Comment: Short and simple ....`ANSWER : 1` Both result are same when you use first statement `ANSWER` with  `UNION`  `ANSWER 2 ` : `SECOND` one is faster then `FIRST` one

Comment: @Harshad both results are not same unless you use `union` in first statement.

Comment: I update my answer. I wonder if the time complexity of two statements are the same?  @Harshad

Comment: @Bharadwaj, `UNION ALL` is better here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran execution plan on 3 different queries.

First query: Using `UNION`

Second query: Using `UNION ALL`

Third query: Using `IN`

```
USE AdventureWorksLT2012

-- First query using UNION
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 716
UNION
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 727
UNION
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 770

-- Second query using UNION ALL
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 716
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 727
UNION ALL
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID = 770

-- Third query using IN
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductID IN(716, 727, 770)
```

[image]

As you can see the `UNION` is using **53%** (Because `UNION` tries to delete duplicates), `UNION ALL` is costing **34%** and `IN` costs **14%** of whole batch

Comment: In fact, I did not use `UNION` or `UNION ALL `, so  I update my answers.

Answer (score 2):

First query

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 2197176 ..
```

returns rows with an id column value equal with specific value in this case 2197176 multiple select returns union  of results.

In the second query

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id IN (2197176, 74877, ...);
```

returns rows where the id column value equals with 2197176 or 74877 or ... .

In equal parameter result of both query are the same records, but in readability and performance second query are better.

Answer (score 0):

IN (val1,val2,val3, ...) is an abbreviated form of filtering predicates inside a WHERE clause and not directly related to the select keyword.

```
SELECT
    column,list, ...
FROM
    table
        JOIN othertables ON ...
WHERE
    table.id IN (1,2,3)
```

This could be re-written as:

```
SELECT
    column,list, ...
FROM
    table
        JOIN othertables ON ...
WHERE 
 (  table.id = 1
 OR table.id = 2
 OR table.id = 3
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the time complexity of first statement is `m*n`, will the second statement be `m*n`?

> - `m`: the time complexity of `SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 2197176;`.
> - `n`: the amount of ids.

No.  The second statement will be the same complexity as the first, but with a larger constant for n.

HOWEVER, if you have an index on the table for ID then complexity of the first is 1 and the second is n.  (Which is still the same since n = 1 in the first case.)

Comment: If I don't have an index on the table for ID, Why the two statements are the same complexity?

Comment: I updated my answer and added the cases. In the two cases, which case is faster and why?

Comment: @DanielJyc - You did not ask which is faster, you asked what the complexity is.  Complexity does not always correspond to speed.   However, in every case the 2nd one will be faster.